# Problem mounting raid 0 NTFS drives in Ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mount, ntfs, raid, gpt

I have 2 disks, **sda** and **sdc** with the following `gdisk` output:

```
$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 7814037168 sectors, 3.6 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 83E2C8AF-B99A-4DF3-84F2-6783DA14E485
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 7814037134
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 0 sectors (0 bytes)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              34            2081   1024.0 KiB  4201  LDM metadata partition
   2            2082          262177   127.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved part
   3          262178      7814037134   3.6 TiB     4200  LDM data partition

$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdc
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdc: 7814037168 sectors, 3.6 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 1FB7A5CB-94F3-490D-883A-2BB598F9794E
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 7814037134
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 0 sectors (0 bytes)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              34            2081   1024.0 KiB  4201  LDM metadata partition
   2            2082          262177   127.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved part
   3          262178      7814037134   3.6 TiB     4200  LDM data partition
```

There is no `blkid` information for either of this disks, only for the OS:

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sdb1: UUID="e7679bdc-374c-416a-affe-4e5f3eefdfab" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdb5: UUID="07c5f04e-e173-42ad-a6f8-429b9d035f2b" TYPE="swap"
```

I have tried mounting the NTFS raid using variations of `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sd[ac][1-3] /mnt`, but fails with the same response:

```
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda3' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

It seems obvious that the disks are not NTFS formatted, but I formatted them in Windows and checked the disks before I plugged them into the ubuntu environment - so definitly are NTFS.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can mount the RAID 0 disks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both disks have partitions of type 4200 and 4201, which denote Microsoft [Logical Disk Manager (LDM),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Disk_Manager) which is Microsoft's equivalent to the Linux Logical Volume Manager (LVM). As such, you can't mount these partitions directly, because the filesystems they contain are held in containers *within* the partitions. The Linux kernel includes LDM support, but I don't recall offhand if that support is included in Ubuntu. If it is, you'll see device files for the logical volumes in the Linux `/dev/mapper/` directory, or a subdirectory thereof. I recommend you check there. You clearly already know how to use `blkid`, so you can use it to identify NTFS volumes.

One more thing: You said these disks are RAID 0 devices. If this was set up with the motherboard's software RAID, you'll need to activate that support, as described here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto

Note that the RAID devices are likely to show up in `/dev/mapper`, too. Using LDM on top of dmraid could get complex. (I've never used this particular combination.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked the `/dev/mapper`, but the devices did not show up there either. It just got to painful, so I ended up taking the easy way out; reformatting the disks and setting up a new RAID 0 array. Thanks anyway :)